# Update data request with ktorfit

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, httprequest, multipartform-data, ktor

hello everyone I'm trying to make a request to update a data with file to the server using ktorfit but when i send a request the data doesnt upload in the server it works fine with adding data what im doing wrong , i will provide my code down here:

```
    override suspend fun updateCourse(
        id: Int,
        description: String,
        price: String,
        title: String,
        category_id: Int,
        photoPart: File
    ): String? {
        val token = tokenFlow.firstOrNull()

        val multipart = MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
            append("photo", photoPart.readBytes(), Headers.build {
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${photoPart.name}")
            }
            )
            append("title", title)
            append("description", description)
            append("price", price)
            append("category_id", category_id)
        }
        )

        Log.d(
            "AddCourse",
            "updateFile: $id description: $description  title: $title  ,,,,,, $photoPart"
        )

        return updateApi.updateCourse(
            "Bearer $token",
            id = id,
            map = multipart
        )
    }

interface UpdateApi {

    @PUT("api/v1/courses/{id}")
    suspend fun updateCourse(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Path("id") id:Int,
        @Body map: MultiPartFormDataContent
    ):String?
}

  @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideKtorClient(
        tokenFlow: Flow<String?>
    ):HttpClient
    {
        val token = runBlocking {
            tokenFlow.firstOrNull() // Fetch the token asynchr onously
        }

        return HttpClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json(Json { isLenient = true; ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
            }
            install(Logging) {
                logger = Logger.DEFAULT
                level = LogLevel.ALL
            }
            token?.let {
                headers {
                    append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer $it")
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

////////////////////////////////////////
any solutions?

Comment: You can observe via Wireshark or a similar tool what HTTP request is actually sent. That may give you an idea of what's wrong.

Comment: What is the content type of the title, description, etc, data ? Should it be passed in json ?

Comment: @bcordier yes and i tried application/json and multipart/form-data but no difference

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what i see, the main issues are :

- You do not specify the content type for the metadata (title, description, etc)
- As you want to pass it as a json, you need to provide it properly formatted. A simple string will not be considered valid json. A minimal example would be :

  "{ "title": "Your title" }"

My suggestion is to create a data class for all your metadata, mark it as serializable and provide it in the correct format. You can either create the metadata object inside your method or do as in my example and provide it from the outside. Here is an example, i’m using Kotlin Serialization but any serialization library will do :

```
import io.ktor.client.request.forms.MultiPartFormDataContent
import io.ktor.client.request.forms.formData
import io.ktor.http.Headers
import io.ktor.http.HttpHeaders
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import java.io.File

@Serializable
data class Metadata(
    val id: Int,
    val description: String,
    val price: String,
    val title: String,
    val category_id: Int,
)

override suspend fun updateCourse(
    metadata: Metadata
    photoPart: File
): String? {
     val token = tokenFlow.firstOrNull()

     val multipart = MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
        append("photo", photoPart.readBytes(), Headers.build {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${photoPart.name}")
        }
        )
        append("metadata", Json.encodeToString(metadata),
            Headers.build {
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "application/json")
            }
        )
    }
    )

    Log.d(
        "AddCourse",
        "updateFile: ${metadata.id} description: ${metadata.description}  title:     ${metadata.title}  ,,,,,, $photoPart"
    )

    return updateApi.updateCourse(
        "Bearer $token",
        id = metadata.id,
        map = multipart
    )
}
```

Of course, you will maybe need to adapt it as i do not have a knowledge of the api you’re trying to communicate with, so there’s maybe some difference between what the service expect and what is here provided.